# Coefficient of polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Could someone explain to me why
$$
[x^{24}](1-2x^6)^{-31} = 2^4 \binom{4 + 31 - 1}{31 - 1} \, ?
$$

Reads: The coefficient of $x^{24}$ in $(1-2x^6)^{-31} =$ ...

Comment: Wow, 5 question already and you still haven't learned how to use latex on this site. Quite an achievement.

Comment: I'm allergic to latex :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the generalized binomial theorem (that allows for negative exponents) and notice that $\displaystyle (-1)^r\binom{-k}{r} = \binom{k+r-1}{k-1}$

Comment: Hi, do you think you could apply this to my example so I can better understand how it works? Thaanks

Comment: Sure.  Here is the binomial theorem: $\displaystyle (1-2x^6)^{-31} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-31}{n}(-2x^6)^n(1)^{-31-n}$

$\displaystyle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{31+n-1}{31-1}2^nx^{6n}$

Answer (score 2):

The generating function for $\dbinom{n+k-1}k x^k$ is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$. Then finding the $x^{24}$ coefficient of $\frac{1}{(1-2x^6)^{31}}$ is equivalent to finding the $x^4$ coefficient of $\frac{1}{(1-2x)^{31}}$. Then plug in the generating function and the answer follows.

The proof of the generating function can be found everywhere.

Comment: "Everywhere"?..

Comment: Well everywhere one is bound to look for the proof of a generating function...